# How to get WTX node in WMB

Tags: messagebroker, wtx

I'm new to WMB, I've to use WTX node in WMB, **How to get WTX map node in WMB.** I've installed wtx 8.2 and wmb 8.0 on my windows7 32-bit system, both are trail versions. can i get wtx node & transformation extender perspective in wmb trail version?

Answer (score 0):

In what order did you install WMBv8 and WTX Design Studio?

You need to install Design Studio and any WTX maintenance after you have installed the Broker Toolkit. When WTX installs, it informs the Broker Toolkit of its installation directory.

NB. WTX 8.2 is a really old version. 8.4 was release in like 2006/07 I think.

If it needs to be free, you can get the latest released developer edition of IBM Integration Bus (the new name for WebSphere Message Broker) [here](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/us/en/integration-bus), or the beta release of IBM IB v.next [here](https://ibm.biz/iibopenbeta).

Comment: hi Encaitar, thank you for your quick reply,I installed the WMB and WTX in the same way as you said, i have tried with Integration Bus 9.0 also, but there is no use. In one of ibm red books about integrating WTX node in WMB they said copy wtx_es.link & wtx_esdoc.link files from path WTXDesignstudi\wtx_eclips\links  folder to links folder of WMB or any other eclipse installation.

Comment: hi Encaitar, thank you for your quick reply,I installed the WMB and WTX in the same way as you said, i have tried with Integration Bus 9.0 also, but there is no use. In one of ibm red books about integrating WTX node in WMB they said copy wtx_es.link & wtx_esdoc.link files from path WTXDesignstudi\wtx_eclips\links  folder to links folder of WMB or any other eclipse installation, but there is no links\ folder in WMB installation but there is no links folder in WMB installation folder.

Comment: What Red Books copy is that? I found [this page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27023576) of instructions for WTX 8.4. However, if you search Google for "message broker system requirements" then follow the links to version 8/Windows/Supported Software it says that WTX 8.2 is not supported with WMB version 8.0, so I don't know if this configuration is ever going to work. Can you upgrade to WTX 8.4?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install **WebSphere TX for Integration Servers** on top of the installs of the Websphere TX design studio and WMB / IIB toolkit.

The [licensing](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/sla/sladb.nsf/lilookup/206F913452D39F018525795F004F57FD?OpenDocument) of WTX for Int. Servers is specifically designed to allow you to do this.

See the [release notes](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27027542) for more information, especially the install sequence:

> To use IBM WebSphere Transformation Extender for Message Broker, the
>   following products must be installed in the order listed:
>
> For the design time environment:
>
> ```
> WebSphere Message Broker Toolkit
> WebSphere Transformation Extender Design Studio (Tooling)
> WebSphere Transformation Extender for Integration Servers
> ```